# Resizable items with flex display

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to a page as a grid of contiguous resizable boxes. I use the flex display that is perfect for this task except when trying rezize flex items. The box border jumps suddenly to some other place.

The simple code below show this behaviour:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  overflow: auto;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 10px;
  max-width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  flex: 1000 1000 auto;
}

.resize {
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box resize" style="background:   red;">A</div>
  <div class="box resize" style="background: green;">B</div>
  <div class="box" style="background:  blue;">c</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any solution.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. Please add clarification and more detail.

Comment: i don't understand the question.. i copy-pasted your code into a jsFiddle and it seems to resize just fine https://jsfiddle.net/emk3gh4c/

Comment: @Michael_B I have exactly the same problem. drag B to the right side and make it bigger. then, drag A to the right side to make it bigger. Now try to resize the A again. while you are dragging it will jump to the left. Did you find any solution?